# Extension not being installed through magento connect in linux

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

Iam trying to install Magento Extension through magento connect I got the extension key and pasted it in the provided field and started installing but unizipping is done but  cannot get my extension moreover getting Error 503 please help me solve this.
here is my screenshot iam strucked here since half an hour.
[image]

and also getting error 503 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some problem with linux OS now leave that process of installing extensions through magento connect

Lets do this in manual way.

Step 1 :search for required extension/Theme and get the extension key and copy it.

Step 2:Now paste it in [here to download](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php?)

Step 3:Copy the folders and paste them into your Magento root folder but dont forget to merge them.

your theme/extension is now ready to use.

**About 503 Error**

Goto your magento root folder there you can see maintainance.flag file delete it next time if you install using magento uncheck put store in maintenance see below image.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: wow this escalated quickly :)
thankyou.

Comment: Can you expand on 'there is some problem with linux OS'.  I haven't come across this (but I very rarely use connect).

Comment: as the one who questioned already put some screenshot it is being strucked at that process  but the same process if done in Windows it is working perfectly.